# Client not connectd properly in Whatsapp Web JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, whatsapp

I am developing one application using Whatsapp web js. I am using Linux PC to run my server (node js), But When I logged in using a QR code it shows on the mobile like "Google Chrome (Mac OS)". It is supposed to show like "Google Chrome (Linux)" right? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp determines the user client using HTTP headers sent from web.whatsapp.com. WhatsappWebJS pretends to be a Whatsapp Web client so that it can send/receive messages. When connecting, it sends a User Agent string, which Whatsapp uses to identify the client. [This](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/blob/a7b77e15ed73a7f1901ead19ffa3060ec7fba5cf/src/util/Constants.js#L14) line of code does that. It clearly sends a MacOS User Agent string regardless of your device. So the code is working as expected.

This shouldn't affect your script in any way. It just affects what shows up in the Whatsapp app. Since it doesn't really matter what shows up there, nothing should go wrong because of this. The "Google Chrome (Mac OS)" is what shows up in Whatsapp, but in reality you are not using Chrome at all; you're running NodeJS code on Linux :) Hope this clarified things!

Answer (score 0):

Only supports Ubuntu Linux.

Change your operating system.